# Google map users live camera position?

Tags: flutter, api, dictionary

I have users current coordinates and google map camera position should be users current location the coordinates i got from users i am unable to passs in latlang

```
 Future<void> Locationservice() async {
    bool _serviceEnabled;
    LocationData locationData;
    Location location = Location();
    PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;

_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
}

_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {}
}

locationData = await location.getLocation();


}

  @override
  void initState() {
    Locationservice();
    super.initState();
 }
```

i am unable to pass coordinated dynamically

```
 body: Stack(children: [
    GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.hybrid,
      initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng( (user lat) , (user lang) ),
        zoom: 14.4746,
      ),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      },
    ),
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i am unable to pass coordinated dynamically" ? create a `LatLng` object above the `build` method and update it when you have users' location from `locationData`. Make sure to rebuild the UI once this object is updated.

Comment: declare LatLng outside the Locationservice function and use setstate to update the location as the user moves

Comment: @AliAkber could u please write the for me ?  iam new to flutter

Comment: I'm assuming all of the above code is in the same class, then you can do something like this: 
 
First move `LocationData locationData;` outside of Locationservice() and make it class level.

Secondly set the state when you get the location data
```setState(() async{
    locationData = await location.getLocation();
});```

and lastly use this location data in the google maps widget
```initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(locationData.latitude, locationData.longitude),
        zoom: 14.4746,
      )```

Hope this helps!